# How to use the return of function to fill in a DropDownMenu in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, odoo

I have this method that returns a list filled with items from an api and I want to use it to fill a dropdownmenuItem using this

```
data.map((item) {
   return DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(
            item['animals_id']),
            value: item['animals_id'],
            );
            }).toList(),
```

the methode in question that i used to fill that list with from api is

```
getIaDetailsByAnimalID() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(URL +
            '/api/optifarm.ia_detail/?query={animals_id,name,order_animal,date_animal,date_identification_animal,sexe_animal,choix,sur_chaleur,prix,product_id}'),
        headers: {'Cookie': 'session_id=${v.session}'});
    List<IaDetails> data = [];
    var mJson = json.decode(response.body)['result'];
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      for (var item in mJson) {
        data.add(IaDetails.fromJson(item));
      }
      return data;
    }
  }
```

I want to use the same data in this "List data = [];" to fill the dropdownmenuItems

I'm still new to dart/flutter development so I appreciate any help given

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 0):

Is your dropdown list based on a stateful widget? If it is, store the data as a property of the state, then just update it within a setState callback.

Something along these lines should work for you:

```
class DropDownMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropDownMenu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DropDownMenuState createState() => _DropDownMenuState();
}

class _DropDownMenuState extends State<DropDownMenu> {
  List<IaDetails> data = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: data.map((item) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Text(item['animals_id']),
          value: item['animals_id'],
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }

  void getIaDetailsByAnimalID() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(URL +
            '/api/optifarm.ia_detail/?query={animals_id,name,order_animal,date_animal,date_identification_animal,sexe_animal,choix,sur_chaleur,prix,product_id}'),
        headers: {'Cookie': 'session_id=${v.session}'});
    List<IaDetails> newData = [];
    var mJson = json.decode(response.body)['result'];
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      for (var item in mJson) {
        newData.add(IaDetails.fromJson(item));
      }

      // Updating this.data within setState will rebuild the 
      // widget tree based on the new data.
      setState(() {
        data = newData;
      });
    }
  }
}
```